# how to write a formula for following problem in simple?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

X = defined 
Y = Undefined 
Y - 25%Y = x 
example: 
X = 65000 
Y - 25% = 65000 
 
How Can I write a formula for Y?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Y-25%Y=75%Y and 75%Y=X  75%=.75   Can you solve for Y now?

Comment: Y= X ÷ 0.75 
 -  Thanks a milion